# Множественный вызов фнукций

Tags: php, функции

Объясните пожалуйста следующую конструкцию из Laravel

```
Foo::set($arr)->
        where('two', '=', '2')->
            orderBy('id')->get();
```

Решил разобраться как это работает, и немного завис..Сначала, мы вызываем статическую функцию where класса Foo, а вот что потом происходит? Как функция может вызываться из функции (where()->where())? Я вот этого не понимаю..Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! С этим вроде понятно. Но а если я передаю конкретный массив? Как быть? (исправил в вопросе) Я хочу написать свой класс Linq, который бы обрабатывал массивы

Comment: Без разницы что вы передаете в метод. Метод каждый раз возвращает ссылку на экземпляр класса.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все понял)

Comment: кстати, статическую функцию `set` вы вызываете сначала, а не `where`